# Sql Subquery with sum

Tags: sql, subquery

I have two tables Invoices and Payments. invoices have payments. I want to write a query that displays unpaid invoices and the remaining amount of the invoice, which is calculated by summing up the payments of the invoice and subtracting it from the invoice amount. I tried this query but it doesn't work. please how can i do it.

```
SELECT Invoice.[Invoice Date], Invoice.Item, Invoice.Quantity, 
    Invoice.[Unit Price], 
    Invoice.[Payment Status], Invoice.[LongDate], 
    Invoice.Quantity*Invoice.[Unit Price] - Sum(Q.Amount) AS Remaining
FROM  
    (SELECT Invoice.[Invoice Id], [Payment ID]
       FROM Invoice 
       INNER JOIN Payment ON Invoice.[Invoice Id] = Payment.[Invoice Id]) AS Q
    INNER JOIN Invoice ON Q.[Invoice Id] = Invoice.[Invoice Id]
GROUP BY Invoice.[Invoice Id];
```

Comment: For what database?  Please include version.

Comment: Why do you need info for each of the item, esp. when you need the balance amount? Does the payment table store records for each item for a given invoice? (I don't think so)

Comment: "I tried this query but it doesn't work."  In what way doesn't it work?  Syntax error?  Wrong result set?  Please give details: sample data, expected outcome, error messages and specifics of undesirable behaviour.

Comment: What is 'Q.Amount'? Can you post your table definitions?

Comment: Have to assume that `amount` exists in the `PAYMENT` table - that's why your query fails, because you have `SUM(Q.amount)` but there's no amount column in the `Q` derived table/subquery

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    Invoice.[Invoice Id],
    Invoice.Quantity * Invoice.[Unit Price] - COALESCE(Amount, 0) AS Remaining
FROM Invoice
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [Invoice Id], SUM(Amount) AS Amount
    FROM Payment
    GROUP BY [Invoice Id]
) T1
ON Invoice.[Invoice Id] = T1.[Invoice Id]
```

Of course you will also need to add the other columns to the select too, but I don't think they are relevant to this question so I omitted them for clarity.

Here is some test data I used to test this:

```
CREATE TABLE Invoice ([Invoice Id] INT NOT NULL, Quantity INT NOT NULL, [Unit Price] INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO Invoice ([Invoice Id], Quantity, [Unit Price]) VALUES
(1, 10, 5),
(2, 20, 10),
(3, 1, 1);

CREATE TABLE Payment ([Invoice Id] INT NOT NULL, Amount INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO Payment ([Invoice Id], Amount) VALUES
(1, 10),
(2, 100),
(2, 15);
```

And the result with this data:

```
Id  Remaining
1   40
2   85
3   1
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, but my database is in access an i think COALESCE is not in access.

Comment: @user249641: I think you have to use `NZ` instead. Remember always to tag the type of database in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Invoice.[Invoice ID], 
    Sum(Invoice.Quantity * Invoice.[Unit Price]) 
    - COALESCE(Sum(Payment.Amount), 0) AS Remaining
FROM
    Invoice LEFT JOIN Payment ON Invoice.[Invoice ID] = Payment.[Invoice ID]
GROUP BY Invoice.[Invoice ID]
```

EDIT: I am assuming, you won't need Item related information in the result.
`LEFT JOIN` is used with an assumption that Invoice might not have a Payment record.

Comment: When testing this I get `Incorrect syntax near 'Invoice'`.  Aren't you missing a comma between the fields in your select statement?

Comment: Corrected. Thanks Mark. I wrote the query without testing it.

Comment: Now gives `Invalid column name 'InvoiceID'`, should be [Invoice ID], and I think you're missing a GROUP BY?

Comment: @Mark: I think I should have tried the query with an example to see if it works. I think writing it straight into textbox on SO without checking is not the right way to answer.

Comment: @Jonathan: Seems possible (and likely) that an invoice would have no payments at some point in time, so it would have to be a left join if you're searching for invoice that are *not* fully paid.

Comment: @Aaronoaght: yes, you're probably right, but then you have to deal with the null 'Payment.Amount', perhaps with NVL or something similar.

Comment: @Jonathan: I have edited the answer with `COALESCE` to handle null values (i.e if there are no rows in Payment table).

Comment: @shahkalpesh: Have you considered how the OP can select the extra fields they need? Just adding them to this query will give an error (if it were MySQL it would work, but I'd guess that it is Sql Server).

Comment: @Mark: I think OP wouldn't need it. Showing the remaining amount for each of the invoice item will give a wrong picture. If the OP wants to average the pending amount for each item, it will be a different SQL.

Comment: @shahkalpesh: Actaully I meant fields like Invoice.[Payment Status] and Invoice.[LongDate] that are in his original query.

Comment: @Mark: Yes. But I am unable to understand why is OP storing records in this fashion? (i.e if the invoice could have more than 1 item)